# How to specify a username with a @ embedded in a URL? ( Mercurial - MacHg related but not specificaly )

Tags: version-control, mercurial, machg

As MacHg (MacOS mercurial client) requests a password but not a username, the only way I have to include the login information for MacHg to connect to a mercurial repository server is to add it in the URL, as the help states.
The problem is that I'm using a repository at Kiln.net where usernames are emails.
So the @ of the email breaks the syntax, example:
`https://user@mailhost.com:passwoidhere@hghost.com/repo`

So can I escape it in some way? urlencoding the @ to a `%40` (or whatever it corresponds) didn't work. `\@` didn't either.

I was able to clone the repo from the command line, but I'd like to use MacHg.

Comment: You should encode it if you put it in the url, I guess it's a bug in machg if it doesn't work (hg itself should work fine, I remember testing it a while ago).

Comment: Thanks, actually %40 for the @ worked, but not until the third try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked, just had to keep trying.